# pandas concat dataframe by converting all columns to json

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this

```
import pandas as pd                                                                         
technologies = [                                                                            
            ("Spark", 22000,'30days',1000.0),                                               
            ("PySpark",25000,'50days',2300.0),                                              
            ("Hadoop",23000,'55days',1500.0)                                                
            ]                                                                               
df = pd.DataFrame(technologies,columns = ['Courses','Fee','Duration','Discount'])           
print(df) 

   Courses    Fee Duration  Discount
0    Spark  22000   30days    1000.0
1  PySpark  25000   50days    2300.0
2   Hadoop  23000   55days    1500.0
```

I want the output to be converted to the following.

```
Courses    Fee Duration  Discount       json
  Spark  22000   30days    1000.0       {"Courses":"Spark","Fee":22000,"Duration":"30days","Discount":1000.0}
PySpark  25000   50days    2300.0       {"Courses":"PySpark","Fee":25000,"Duration":"50days","Discount":2300.0}
 Hadoop  23000   55days    1500.0       {"Courses":"Hadoop","Fee":23000,"Duration":"55days","Discount":1500.0}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a lambda function to create the new `json` column

```
import json
import pandas as pd

df['json'] = df.apply(lambda row: json.dumps(dict(row)), axis=1)
```

Alternatively, if you want to get the entire DataFrame as a list of dicts you may use

```
df.to_dict(orient='records')
```

PS: wrap your lambda operation with `json.dumps()` as necessary (depending on if you want the output as `dict` or `JSON`)

Comment: Both solution return dict, not json.

Comment: @jezrael thanks for pointing that out! I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: It is common mistake - OP need dict, but think it is json.

Answer (score 1):

Because need `json` need convert dictionary from [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) to `json` by `json.dumps`:

```
import json

df['dict'] = df.to_dict(orient='records')

df['json'] = [json.dumps(x) for x in df.to_dict(orient='records')]
print (df)
   Courses    Fee Duration  Discount  \
0    Spark  22000   30days    1000.0   
1  PySpark  25000   50days    2300.0   
2   Hadoop  23000   55days    1500.0   

                                                dict  \
0  {'Courses': 'Spark', 'Fee': 22000, 'Duration':...   
1  {'Courses': 'PySpark', 'Fee': 25000, 'Duration...   
2  {'Courses': 'Hadoop', 'Fee': 23000, 'Duration'...   

                                                json  
0  {"Courses": "Spark", "Fee": 22000, "Duration":...  
1  {"Courses": "PySpark", "Fee": 25000, "Duration...  
2  {"Courses": "Hadoop", "Fee": 23000, "Duration"...
```

---

```
print (type(df.loc[0, 'dict']))
<class 'dict'>

print (type(df.loc[0, 'json']))
<class 'str'>
```